# mcrypt deprecated message. How do I switch to an alternative like openssl?

Tags: magento-1.9, mcrypt

I'm getting this error that mycrypt is deprecated. I've heard I should use openssl. But I'm not sure how would I go about this in terms of my Magento 1.9 setup. Can I get some insight? Also how serious is this problem?

ERR (3): Deprecated functionality: Function mdecrypt_generic() is deprecated  in /home/customer/www/sciencellonline.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 130

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate vanilla Magento 1 to OpenMage 19 or 20 which is an active project on GitHub. This issue was solved long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to a PHP version <=7.1. Higher versions are not compatible with your Magento version.

More info:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mdecrypt-generic.php

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately, I cannot switch back to an older php version either. Is there another way?

Comment: You should run a script which checks for compatibility of PHP version and fix all issues in the code. I think companies like MageOne provide patches to make M1 compatible with newer php versions. You can also look into that